# Aws lambda supports mongoose middleware?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-lambda

Does AWS lambda supports mongoose middleware, I'm using `.pre()` to check data exists on save.

here is my function call for save

```
res = new cModel();     
res.pre('save', function (next) {
                                    cModel.find({name: company.name}, function (err, docs) {
                                        if (!docs.length){
                                            next();
                                        }else{                
                                            console.log('company name exists: ',company.name);
                                            next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
                                        }
                                    });
                                }) ;
```

this is my function call to update

```
company_model.companySchema.pre('update', function (next) {
                                try {
                                    cModel.find({ name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${this.getFilter().name}$` , 'i') }}, function (err, docs) {
                                        try {
                                            if (!docs.length) {
                                                next();
                                            } else {
                                                console.log('company name exists: ', this.getFilter().name);
                                                next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
                                            }
                                        } catch (e) {
                                            console.error('error in cModel.find: ' + e.message);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (e) {
                                    console.error('error in pre save : ' + e.message)
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't, given that you properly wait for all async methods to finish executing. Why would you expect it not to? Do you have some code to showcase the problem?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech updated with function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eInside a `pre('save',...` hook, the reference to the current document is found under `this`. Here I've replaced `company` with `this` in your example.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({})
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  cModel.find({name: this.name}, function (err, docs) {
    if (!docs.length){
      next();
    } else {                                 
      console.log('company name exists: ', this.name);
      next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
    }
  });
});
const cModel = mongoose.model("cmodel", schema)
```

This error doesn't have anything to do with lambda, except that the execution environment in lambda seems to be swallowing the error in the async method. To see the error being thrown, you can wrap the contents of your callback in a `try {...} catch (e) {...}` block and log the error in the catch block:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({})    
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  try {
    cModel.find({name: this.name}, function (err, docs) {
      try {
        if (!docs.length){
          next();
        } else {                                 
          console.log('company name exists: ', this.name);
          next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('error in cModel.find: ' + e.message)
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error in pre save : ' + e.message)
  }
});
const cModel = mongoose.model("cmodel", schema)
```

---

### Update

Using `.pre('update'...` will have `this` referencing the query, not the document, as the document is never loaded. You can access parts of the query using `getFilter()` and `getUpdate()`.

Here is an example to check if company exists before making an update:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({})
schema.pre('update', function (next) {
  let newName = this.getUpdate().name;
  cModel.find({name: newName }, function (err, docs) {
    if (!docs.length){
      next();
    } else {                                 
      console.log('company name exists: ', newName);
      next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
    }
  });
});
const cModel = mongoose.model("cmodel", schema)
```

Comment: @Farhan Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't check what I wrote. The `pre` hooks need to be defined on the schema, not on a document.

Comment: @Farhan in a pre `update` hook you do not have a reference to the document as it isn't loaded. The update happens in the Database, it doesn't first fetch the document to your code and then update it. `this` is a `pre('update',...)` hook will be a reference to the query, so instead you could use `this.getFilter().name` to get the company name inside your hook. The rest would stay the same.

Comment: That didn't worked, updated the question with `update function` can you verify? Also if possible can you write if its not correct?

Comment: You need to show how it didn't work - was there an error? And please include the query you are running to test this, and your intentions for what it should do. Maybe it should be `this.getUpdate().name` if you want to check the name that it will be updated to, rather than the name that it was

Comment: So here's a situation, while updating when I'm note doing any changes, and clicking save, it says the name exists. its checking things which is not updated, Any solution for this?

Comment: @Farhan did you try using `getUpdate()`? I've updated my answer. At this point this question / answer has had too many edits to be useful to anyone coming in with the same problem, so rather than making another edit, please ask a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324732/mongo-using-mongoose-in-node-want-to-use-or-and-in-query 
can you check this?